# Vue Component name "TheConfirm" should always be multi-word

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I got error using VueJS 3
"Component name "TheConfirm" should always be multi-word"
despite the fact, that the name is multiword; i tried also:
"the_confirm", "the-confrim";
but every time i refresh and i got the same error:
"Component name "TheConfirm" should always be multi-word";

heres the App:

```
<template>
Main app
</template>

<script>

import AppCos from './components/TheConfirm.vue';

</script>

<style>
@import './assets/style.css';
</style>
```

and here is TheComponent:

```
<template>
    confirm
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Do you have the confirm component inside your main.js vs?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    The Component
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TheComponent',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the configuration item and turn off the syntax check: find (do not create) the vue.config.js file in the project root directory, add lintOnSave: false

like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w97UR.png)